# How to insert a variable in MySQLi statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert data in a database using MYSQLi. If I use the following query, data is inserted;

```
INSERT INTO table (Name, Phone, Location) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test')
```

Instead of the value 'test', I need the value of a variable inserted. However the following does not work.

```
$test = 'xxx';
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (Name, Phone, Location) VALUES (".$test.", 'aaa', 'bbb')")) {
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
}
```

I have tried the `bind_param` command, but it didn't work.

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $phone, $location);
```

How can I insert a variable directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the code should be like this:

```
$test = 'xxx';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (Name, Phone, Location) VALUES (?, 'aaa', 'bbb')");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

If you want to have 3 variables for this query:

```
$name = "My name";
$phone = "My phone number";
$location = "My location";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (Name, Phone, Location) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $phone, $location);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: So that was the error I have been making. I needed three "s" because there are three strings. Thank you so much. Will accept answer ASAP.